# how to redirect in PHP without javascript or Headers

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, url-routing

I was wondering if there is any way I can redirect my login page automatically to another page.php without using Javascript at all or headers, because I already try with the last ones, but I need to send some echo before that.

You see, is for a log-in process, after the log-in i wanna be capable of send different users to different page.php according to the type of user this will be, so that will be the propose of this.

I've already checked for this matter before but I can't find a single answer than doesn't suggest the use of headers, or JavaScript.

If you see some other question than actually answer this please link it but first be sure it actually doesn't use JavaScript or headers to do it.

Comment: You can use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; ,URL=http://www.example.com">`

Comment: Did you Google your title before asking a question like this? It's pointless to even put in an answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have mentioned in the question that you don't want to use headers. Probably because you can't echo a message, But using the header below you can both echo a message and redirect a user to next page.

```
header( "refresh:5; url=wherever.php" ); //Redirect page after five seconds.
echo 'Redirecting in 5 seconds';
```

EDIT: Redirect users to different URLs.

```
$url = 'user_home.php';
if($user == 'admin'){
   $url = 'admin_home.php';
}

header( "refresh:5; url= $url" ); //Redirect page after five seconds.
echo 'Redirecting you to your home in 5 seconds. Please wait.';
```

Comment: OP specifically mentioned he doesn't want to use `header`

Comment: @asprin He doesn't want to use headers because he can't echo. I gave him a solution which allows him to use headers with echo. The reason is mentioned in the answer.

Comment: i re-read the question and you are truth, i say about i don't want to echo and i forget to put more detail in the log-in part of the question.

It's for a log-in process, after this one the idea is send the user to the specific .php acording to what kind of user he is.

Sorry for my mistake, i already correct it in the question thanks for the answer in any case

Comment: @user57129 see updated answer. It will cover your requirement of using different urls.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />'
```

Echo this in the `<head></head>` section of your page

Comment: Thre problem is, this is for a log-in process, i don't wanna send unauthorize persons to that .php specificaly, in any case, thanks for the help